# MyBatis 3 + Spring 3: select returns null values

Tags: spring, mybatis

I builded a project based on the MyBatis examples (I also examined the [JPetStore 6 application](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/sample.html)).

The problem is that my getTrains() method always returns null objects.
Here is the source files and the configuration ones:

TrainMapper.java

```
package org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence;

import java.util.List;
import org.example.mybatis.spring.domain.Train;

public interface TrainMapper {

    Train getTrain(int id);
    List<Train> getTrains();
    void insertTrain(Train train);
}
```

TrainService.java

```
package org.example.mybatis.spring.service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.example.mybatis.spring.domain.Train;
import org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence.TrainMapper;

@Service("trainService")

public class TrainService {

@Autowired
private TrainMapper trainMapper;

public void setTrainMapper(TrainMapper trainMapper) {
    this.trainMapper = trainMapper;
}

public Train getTrain(int id) {
    return this.trainMapper.getTrain(id);
}

public List<Train> getTrains() {
    return this.trainMapper.getTrains();
}

@Transactional
public void insertTrain(Train train) {
    this.trainMapper.insertTrain(train);
}
```

}

TrainMapper.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

    <mapper namespace="org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence.TrainMapper">
      <cache />
      <select id="getTrain" resultType="Train" parameterType="int">
        SELECT
          train_type
        FROM trains
        WHERE trains.train_id = #{id}
      </select>
      <select id="getTrains" resultType="org.example.mybatis.spring.domain.Train" parameterType="int">
        SELECT
          train_type
        FROM trains
      </select>
      <insert id="insertTrain" parameterType="Train">
        INSERT INTO trains (train_type)
        VALUES (#{type})
      </insert>
    </mapper>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mysql.jdbc.properties" />

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.example.mybatis.spring" />

  <tx:annotation-driven />

  <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="org.example.mybatis.spring.domain" />
    <!--property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/-->
    <!--property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:org/example/mybatis/spring/persistence/*.xml" /-->
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Train.java is a simple Java bean.

The project POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>mybatis-spring-example</artifactId>
  <name>MyBatis-Spring Example</name>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <description>Example of the MyBatis-Spring integration (within a Maven project)</description>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.20</mysql.connector.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <mybatis.version>3.1.1</mybatis.version>
    <mybatis.spring.version>1.1.1</mybatis.spring.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.2.8</hsqldb.version>
    <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
    <nexus.ip>x.y.w.z</nexus.ip>
    <nexus.port>xxxx</nexus.port>
    <nexus.public.group.url>http://${nexus.ip}:${nexus.port}/nexus/content/groups/public</nexus.public.group.url>
    <nexus.releases.url>http://${nexus.ip}:${nexus.port}/nexus/content/repositories/releases</nexus.releases.url>
    <nexus.snapshots.url>http://${nexus.ip}:${nexus.port}/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</nexus.snapshots.url>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus-internal-repo</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Internal Repository</name>
      <url>${nexus.public.group.url}</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
  <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
  <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
  <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
  <version>${mybatis.spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>cglib</groupId>
  <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
  <version>${cglib.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I run the application as standalone:

```
package org.example.mybatis.spring;

import java.util.List;
import org.example.mybatis.spring.domain.Train;
import org.example.mybatis.spring.service.TrainService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class SelectTrainExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "applicationContext.xml");
            TrainService trainBean = (TrainService) context.getBean("trainService");

            List<Train> trains = trainBean.getTrains();
            System.out.println(trains.toString());

            Train train = trainBean.getTrain(1);
            System.out.println(train.toString());

            Train t = new Train();
            t.setType("Interregionale");
            trainBean.insertTrain(t);
        }
    }
```

The insert in the database work fine, while I'm not be able to retrieve data from the "trains" table.
Here is the log output:

> 2012-10-01 15:25:03,400 DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] -
>    2012-10-01 15:25:03,413 DEBUG
>   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - 
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,463 DEBUG
>   [org.apache.ibatis.cache.decorators.LoggingCache] -  2012-10-01
>   15:25:03,473 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] -  2012-10-01 15:25:03,474 DEBUG
>   [org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction] -  2012-10-01 15:25:03,479 DEBUG
>   [org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence.TrainMapper.getTrains] -  2012-10-01
>   15:25:03,497 DEBUG
>   [org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence.TrainMapper.getTrains] - <==> 
>   Preparing: SELECT train_type FROM trains > 2012-10-01 15:25:03,578
>   DEBUG [org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence.TrainMapper.getTrains] -
>   <==> Parameters: > 2012-10-01 15:25:03,660 DEBUG
>   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - 
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,661 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] -  [null, null, null, null, null]
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,664 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory]
>   -  2012-10-01 15:25:03,668 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] -
>    2012-10-01 15:25:03,669
>   DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] -
>   
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,673 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] -
>   
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,674 DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] -
>    2012-10-01 15:25:03,674 DEBUG
>   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - 
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,679 DEBUG
>   [org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction] -  2012-10-01 15:25:03,679 DEBUG
>   [org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence.TrainMapper.insertTrain] -
>    2012-10-01
>   15:25:03,679 DEBUG
>   [org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence.TrainMapper.insertTrain] -
>   <==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO trains (train_type) VALUES (?) >
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,680 DEBUG
>   [org.example.mybatis.spring.persistence.TrainMapper.insertTrain] -
>   <==> Parameters: Interregionale(String)> 2012-10-01 15:25:03,681 DEBUG
>   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - 
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,681 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] -
>    2012-10-01 15:25:03,683 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] -
>    2012-10-01 15:25:03,727 DEBUG
>   [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] - 
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,727 DEBUG [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils] -
>   
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,728 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] -
>   
>   2012-10-01 15:25:03,728 DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] -

Note that I ran the same example using JDBC, and it worked fine.

Libraries and environment:
Spring 3.1.2
MyBatis 3.1.1
MyBatis-Spring 1.1.1
MySQL 5.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to the answer on your other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936618/mybatis-select-statement-returns-null-values

Comment: Is this example working for you ? I following the same and found spring exception at run time that TrainMapper dependency bean not found exception

Answer (score 0):

you have not post your "Train" java bean.  But in Insert statement you use #{type}, I guest that your bean property names are "id" and "type". But in database table the field names are "id" and "train_type". Mybatis don't know how to map table fields to java bean properties. In Mapper.xml you have not add result map. There are two methods:

1. add resultMap Element in your mapper.xml to tell mybiatis how to map database table field name to java bean property name.
2. in select statements use "as" like this

   SELECT
     train_type as type
   FROM trains